# How to get only full li tags in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having the following

```
<ul class="fullname">
    <li><a href="">some name</a></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>name1</li>
            <li>Name2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <ul>
            <li>name3</li>
            <li>Name4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>         
</ul>
```

I want only three elements in children, in the first index like 
`<li><a href="">some name</a></li>` and second `<ul><li>name1</li><li>Name2</li></ul>`

I have tried the following

```
navContent = content.find("li",{"class":"fullname"})
children = navContent.find_all("li")
```

But in the second index it is giving the `<li>name1</li>` not the whole `li`. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`recursive=False`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument)

From the documentation:

> If you call `mytag.find_all()`, Beautiful Soup will examine all the descendants of `mytag`: its children, its children’s children, and so on. If you only want Beautiful Soup to consider direct children, you can pass in `recursive=False`.

```
navContent = content.find("ul",{"class":"fullname"})
children = navContent.find_all("li", recursive=False)
```